# Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type error for lodash require TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I can't figure out why TS doesn't like the history or lodash requires:

for `_ = require('lodash'),` **I get the TS error** `Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable '_' must be of type 'LoDashStatic', but here has type 'any'`

for `require('connect-history-api-fallback')` **I get the TS error** `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'history'`

`@types/lodash` and `@types/connect-history-api-fallback` are installed already.

**api.ts**

```
const _ = require('lodash'),
  countryTable = require('./shared/data/countries.json'),
  compression = require('compression'),
  express = require('express'),
  { on, use } = (module.exports = express()),
  history = require('connect-history-api-fallback'),
  oneYear = 31536000;

use(compression());

module.exports = on('error', function (err: string) {
  console.log(err);
})
  .get('/api/v1/countries', (res: any) => {
    res.json(
      countryTable.map((country: any) => {
        return _.pick(country, ['id', 'name', 'images']);
      })
    );
  })
  .use(history())
  .use(
    express.static('dist', {
      maxage: oneYear,
    })
  )
  .use((res: any) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,OPTIONS');
    res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json'
    );
    res.send('Sorry, Page Not Found');
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript doesn't like that your `const history` conflicts with `window.history` in the global scope which is provided by the browser.

If you just change the name to `historyApi` it should all work as you expect:

```
historyApi = require('connect-history-api-fallback'),
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=6&ssc=56&pln=6&pc=3#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+jAvDATgUwI4FcCW6AUA5ADYgAmAhhABaECUANAFAwyhZhQoCeAKhQCNiaJKky4ChAHQB6GhXRkZlKBRntOKHGghSAVhHD1mrUAFsADuggQc4Uemx40Rc1Z22jjFjDQAPdxsHcWcif0CIYx8AbxhwBhgsCBEAX1F8M3IsYSlwkBQoCFFw6wh8Om9WahxofO4AQQscYKdJUDAwNGAoAFpq2p4eiiaegDMKYmIBCmAAayjWcDQATTQFUQBmAEYAVg2ANgAGY4BuJiYklzdSuzByujOmTLJstFyA-MLRcDCUFHzCAlRhxurcYPg0H8AFwwaBaMAAczoMGiPnahhypAREL+DyYKToPikCLQUCIMmGOBkADctuoQBwuNpIgl8NYYRQwNxkYgAHwonysaz6Qx3QWsNgMzR8QQ5MzDfD4DRcbgcrk8-moiXasRQLAoMDwKRNOZKqUqhIAbUIODIgJghDAFDMaHtNvlJMiAF08TqYATxb7-YTWFJLvh+lA6o0cPcieHxSUPFJoBQoDhgEQyDUoPatTr5X4KCSYUtVgoTBKA6wQzAw8lFeyYJzuUhNeLhdQ1mRIUR6sBgB4egBhcBcEDEHr1SYgADuPQA8loETgwG6AFT0M7azvd3uEfuDmwjsf-SfT0jz4eKNCcHATFkwLhYNBBoU6KRdig9lB9gdD0dNAnKcZ3nABZUlqHIR9CAAcQAUV4BgFwABV4ABJBcADkAGUtw7D8vx-fBxVYA9-2PQDx3PUCegACT3FAWVIh0lxwFcwAYAANHoACVxB0KA0DIHoAHUcCgagGCo29el4bgLDQBhDzQCwoAYdohM4HooAUpThgsYgMzTW4ZAMIxA23CVhWSMAyCIHD8h4BIUOLEQsJAWAADEpTtIMCROIA)

Or you could `import` keyword, which doesn't seem to mind overriding globals.

```
import history from 'connect-history-api-fallback'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAC2AZxtAnnAZlCI4DkAxhAHakCmRMAtEqhjQIZjA1ZMA2nARk0QGsCAKGElSqOAH04AXjhQKARwCuwRQAoCnCABMmyBAQCUAGmFw4JFaRhR0AFSY9OFOQuVrNBAHQB6QyZFXT99GCY-a1soYApkHwArZDITc0sScEVkZGAyd0VVdQotDLAsnJSzCzgKAA8yuOR8zyKtOobs1OqAbzgyUzgVZDcAX3cNED0VVx926Bgm+XbyjWMqyzIKAE0KIPcAZgBGAFZ9gDYABiuAblEh4tLy3NJV41vhSd1piln6+cW+i8CBQoLgoAQBlgbNRnnANCCoAAuOCoGKkADmxjg3Wq4mSMx06PhoLewhGxmqPnRFBgWj8LGAfgAbodIhAbHZYsgIXCssimKR0FjZAA+bHVSxZRLJF4SyxWdnRRzOGYgFgaDRROzofmC4VinHyo0eGAqKCkaQ+ViCTWK7UDADaBGAuh5BFITBAFDdoCY1O5AF1Sca4OS5cHQxTLD57hp6Gh7K9KbG5ctGj5UEwYMAiFpdCgYDzDca1bU-RRkZsdkE0vKw5Yo3AY8MNXy4AKhXIDXKpQhdroQVoAIJEIiNGgAYTIdggnBoQ+4EAA7jQAPIxdHAUhugBUJluRt7-cHBBHY+yk+nuDnC50K4nwQotmAXG5AzsKgoEclcR8faYA5QMOo7jlO0SzvOi4rgAsjSCB6G+hAAOIAKIOKYq4AAoOAAkquAByADK+49r+-6ARocqWKeIEXmBM43lBNAABLHlAb5UYQ67AJupCmAAGjQABKnhxDAFC6DQADqwAwAgpj0U+tAOOgYAUKYZ4UGAMCmOI4m2DQMCqepLBgJwOZZs8fhJCk4YHvKUrDKQuhaIR0D2AMmHlnA+EQPAABiiquhG5LXEAA)

In most typescript projects `import` is preferred over `require()` for reasons like this, as well as the fact you need to use `import` to import any types from other files.

So I would recommend changing your `require()`s to `import` statements, and this should give you a lot less trouble.

Comment: thanks.  I can't change to import because webpack complains if I do that for my `server.js` and `api.js`.  server.js is using api.js via require as well.  My React stuff is all using imports